# How Docker Compose And Rabbitmmq Config together?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq-exchange

I built two microservices and RabbitMQ and containerize them by docker...
when I run docker-compose. "yaml up"
i have this error in microservice container " Mass Transit[0] Connection Failed: rabbitmq://localhost/ RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable "
without containerizing them and run by IIssexpress I have no problem

Comment: We would need to see some details about your configuration (e.g., your `docker-compose.yaml` file) in order to answer this question. Just looking at the error message, it's likely the problem is that you're using `localhost` as a hostname when in fact you should be using the name of your rabbitmq container.

Comment: hi...thanks..i slove this problem by changeing code  that coonect to rabbit  by them.